# Script isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

I'm new to html, just started doing it at school, and I'm trying to make this website just to test a few things. For some reason, it only works on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XwN2L/3781/). I am just trying to make the button glow on click. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style media="screen" type="text/css">
    img {
        position: absolute;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
    }
    div#info_box {
        height: 221px;
        width: 221px;
    }
</style>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body background="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2014/113/f/b/rain_by_matt74997-d7fn2e1.gif">
<div id="trigger">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/8QLgeGP.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/BmjwX9A.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://i.imgur.com/8QLgeGP.png'" />
</div>
<div id="info_box" style="display:none">
     <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b3Holdt.png" alt="glow" height="221" width="221">
     <span class="custom info">
</span>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('div#trigger').click(function() {
            //Get info_box
            var info = $('div#info_box');
            //Fade the box in during 1 sec, show it for 5, and let it fade out again
            info.fadeIn(1000).delay(10).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

I tried using google chrome, internet explorer, looking through other answers, but I'm still not sure how to get it to work.

Google chrome says `Uncaught Reference Error: $ is not defined` 
but I'm not sure what to do with that.

If more information could help please ask which and I'll put it up.

Comment: You forget add the Jquery library.

Comment: you forgot to use jQuery library, and for the future, there is 4 boxes in JSFiddle, one for css, javascript, html and last one for result, stick to that, dont mix everything other wise your sample it will not work...

Comment: Add this to your head -
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please include Jquery to the top of the scripts as many plugin use it.

```
http://jquery.com/download/
```

Comment: Worked, downloaded it and linked it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this link to `<head>`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need `jquery` reference when  using `$`

Comment: GET file://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND    It worked when downloaded and linked